# $\delta$-approximative-p-dimensional Hausdorff measure a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Might someone explain why it is necessary to define the Hausdorff-measure as the limit of the outer measure depictured below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer to that is dimensionality: If you pick an arbitrary compact set $K$, then $\mathcal{H}^p_\delta(K)<\infty$. This can be seen by picking a cover of $K$ of open balls with diameter less than $\delta$. Then by compactness you find a finite numer of these balls still covering $K$. Hence they yield an upper bound on $\mathcal{H}^p_\delta(K)$.

Now pick a closed square $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example $Q:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$. This should be a set of dimension two and therefore a $1$-dimensional area measure should yield $\infty$. But $\mathcal{H}^1_\delta(Q) <\infty$ as seen above.

Hence $\mathcal{H}^p_\delta$ does not give you the right term of dimensionality, but $\lim_{\delta\searrow 0}\mathcal{H}^p_\delta$ yields exactly that.

EDIT:
$\mathcal{H}^p_\delta$ is in general not a Borel measure. Let me give you an example: For a straight line $L\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ you can show $\mathcal{H}^1_\delta(L)=\mathcal{H}^1(L) = \mathcal{L}^1(A\circ L)$. Here $A$ is a rotation and translation, such that $L\subset \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}=\mathbb{R}$, i.e. an isometry.
Now let $A=[0,1]\times\{0\}$ and $B=[0,1]\times\{\varepsilon\}$ with $\varepsilon>0$. Then 
$$\mathcal{H}^1_\delta (A) = \mathcal{H}^1_\delta(B)=1$$
hence
$$\mathcal{H}^1_\delta(A) + \mathcal{H}^1_\delta(B)=2,$$
but if you choose $\delta>0$ big enough, $A\cup B$ cover $A\cup B$ and $\operatorname{diam}(A\cup B) < \delta$, but $\operatorname{diam}(A\cup B)=\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2}<2$ if $\varepsilon$ is small enough.
Hence
$$H^1_\delta(A\cup B) <2\mbox{ and } \mathcal{H}^1_\delta(A) + \mathcal{H}^1_\delta(B)=2$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets, $\mathcal{H}^1_\delta$ is not a Borel measure.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. But hasn't it also something to do with the fact that we want to have measure properties for it? Where does the problem lie here for? Again thank you for your help.

Comment: @ Rico1990: Answered question in an edit